# python- tf.write_file does ot work in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a code that train an object coordinate for object detection.
I used CNN network and the output layer is regression layer (called **bound_box_output**) that return (x0,y0, height, width) for an object in an image. After this layer I try to save the image directly before loss step.

```
   i = 0
   image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file('3.jpg'), channels=3)
   cropped = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image = image_decoded,
                                          offset_height = tf.cast(bound_box_output[i,0], tf.int32),
                                          offset_width = tf.cast(bound_box_output[i,1], tf.int32),
                                          target_height = tf.cast(bound_box_output[i,2], tf.int32),
                                          target_width = tf.cast(bound_box_output[i,3], tf.int32))

   enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(cropped)
   fname = tf.constant('4.jpeg')
   fwrite = tf.write_file(fname, enc)
```

and in **tf.train.SessionRunHook** I run it

```
def begin(self):
        self._step = -1
        self._start_time = time.time()

def before_run(self, run_context):
        self._step += 1
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(loss)
def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        if self._step % LOG_FREQUENCY == 0:
          current_time = time.time()
          duration = current_time - self._start_time
          self._start_time = current_time

          loss_value = run_values.results
          examples_per_sec = LOG_FREQUENCY * BATCH_SIZE / duration
          sec_per_batch = float(duration / LOG_FREQUENCY)


          format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                        'sec/batch)')
          print (format_str % (datetime.now(), self._step, loss_value,
                               examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))

        if self._step  == MAX_STEPS-1:
          loss_value = run_values.results
          print("The final value of loss is:: ")
          print(loss_value)
          print(fwrite)
          tf.train.SessionRunArgs(fwrite)
```

**the problem is that it does not save the '4.jpeg' image in a specific folder**

Note: I use **tensorflow 1.1.3** and **python3.5**

Comment: Did the program print the last print statements ("The final value of loss is::", etc.)?

Comment: yes it is, It it for the last step of training

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. The code seems correct, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Have you tried explicitly stating path of the output file? (For example, using `/tmp/4.jpeg` as `fname`. Just to make sure the file writer is actually saving something.

Comment: yes I did that and there is no image saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR;  Substitute `tf.train.SessionRunArgs(fwrite)` with `run_context.session.run(fwrite)`.

[`SessionRunArgs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L192) doesn't actually run the supplied operation. [`SessionRunArgs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L192) are returned from the [`before_run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L132) call. Their role is to add arguments to the next `session.run()` call.

```
if self._step  == MAX_STEPS-1:
  loss_value = run_values.results
  print("The final value of loss is:: ")
  print(loss_value)
  print(fwrite)
  tf.train.SessionRunArgs(fwrite)  # problematic line
```

You are attempting to run the `fwrite` operation in the end of [`after_run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L155).  However, it merely instantiates the [`SessionRunArgs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L192) object.

One option to achieve the desired behavior is to take advantage of the `run_context` argument supplied to [`after_run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L155).  `run_context` is of type [`SessionRunContext`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L216), the type that contains a `session` reference.

`run_context.session.run(fwrite)` should do the trick for you.